# Dequantumizability known and unknown?

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing, big-picture, big-list

Dequantumizable problems have been taking some headlines these days (for example [this blog post by Scott Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3880) and [this article in Quantum Magazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/teenager-finds-classical-alternative-to-quantum-recommendation-algorithm-20180731/)).

1. What are some problems that are currently considered for dequantumization?
2. Is there any governing principles to look for in warning signs in attempting or abandoning dequantumization?

Comment: Search for "quantum inspired"

Comment: This question and answers may be of interest: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41520/fast-classical-simulation-of-quantum-algorithms